# Multilingual Facebook page - audience restrictions

Tags: facebook

A multilingual Facebook page e.g. English and French can be liked and followed by English and French speakers but also by Turkish, Moroccan, Swedish, Finish... thus many other persons that have a different mother tongue but understand either English or French. The level of understanding of English or French for these non-native speakers can vary, nothing stops a person that has a poor level of English to like a Facebook page.

While posting on the Facebook page wall,  since the link preview for translated post does still not work see
[Facebook link preview in multilingual posts not working](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/100351/facebook-link-preview-in-multilingual-posts-not-working/117373), the solution is to restrict the audience based on language and post once with the English link to your website and with audience restricted for language English, and then post a second post with the link to your website in French, and the audience restricted to French.

Would the Swedish, Finish, Turkish, etc. persons get to see that post in English? or in French?
My opinion is that they won't see it.

Based on my research the Facebook language audience restriction will show one post to a user only if he/she can understand it, thus either based on the languages declared by that user in her/his Facebook account or based by the Browser language. My opinion is that very few people are setting the browser language, I know none that do that.

My question is, is there a way that I could target the Swedish Facebook users that liked the page, while not spamming the French users? I could add Swedish, but then I would need to add in the audience restriction Turkish, Bulgarian, Portuguese... all the languages in the world except for French, which I guess it is impossible?

Is there another way then creating an Facebook page for each language? and let's say even if there would be Turkish Facebook fans there, I could still post in English because the French users will be on another Facebook page. I would prefer to avoid this solution, since I already have some thousands of likes... Thus is there any other solution that maybe I do not see.